# How to show related posts of category on post within custom posttype

Tags: custom-post-types, categories, custom-taxonomy, taxonomy

We created a custom posttype called 'Handbook' and it has its own categories. Inside this handbook-category we have categories like 'fase 1', 'fase 2' etc. All the posts in this posttype got one of these categories (fase 1 etc.) selected. On the al the posts in this posttype I need a section with related posts with the same category.

For this I used the following code;

```
function ms_related_kb() {

    $post_id = get_the_ID();
    $cat_ids = array();
    $categories = get_the_category( $post_id );

    if(!empty($categories) && is_wp_error($categories)):
        foreach ($categories as $category):
            array_push($cat_ids, $category->term_id);
        endforeach;
    endif;

    $current_post_type = get_post_type($post_id);
    $query_args = array( 

        'category__in'   => $cat_ids,
        'post_type'      => $current_post_type,
        'post__not_in'    => array($post_id),
        'posts_per_page'  => '5'

     );

    $related_cats_post = new WP_Query( $query_args );
    

    if($related_cats_post->have_posts()):
         while($related_cats_post->have_posts()): $related_cats_post->the_post();
            $postIcon = get_field('artikel_icon');
            $postsList .= '<li class="kb-related-item"><a href="' . get_the_permalink() . '" class="kb-related-link"><div class="kb-related-box"><img src="' . $postIcon[url] . '" alt="ALT" class="kb-related-image"><p class="kb-related-title">' . get_the_title() . '</p></div></a></li>';
        endwhile;
    
        return '<ul class="kb-related-list">' . $postsList . '</ul>';

        // Restore original Post Data
        wp_reset_postdata();
     endif;
}
add_shortcode('ms_related_kennisartikelen', 'ms_related_kb');
```

The problem is that with this code I get all the related posts of the complet posttype 'Handbook'. What do I need to change to get all the related posts of the categories and not the posttype?

Answer (score 0):

@ricardio-de-penning
**I think you are going on wrong direction.
You just want to get only those posts which is related to current category right?**

**If yes then you need to filter post using tax_query like below.**

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'category',
            'field'    => 'term_id',
            'terms'    => array($cat_ids),
            'operator ' => 'IN',
        ),
    ),
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Comment: Yes exactly, but your code does not work. Maybe because it is a custom posttype?

Comment: I hope you changed your arguments based on your query.
Show me what kind of arguments you are passing?

Comment: I first used the code I send above but modified by your code, but didn't work.